# How to install arachni scanner for windows

Tags: windows, installation

I have came across this vulnerability scanner called [Arachni](http://www.arachni-scanner.com/)
but can't find installation and usage instructions for windows users. There is only example for linux users as I understand. The [documentation](https://github.com/Arachni/arachni/wiki) is quite poor.

Answer (score 2):

OK so it seems that i have managed to install it myself:

1. [Download arachni windows package](http://www.arachni-scanner.com/download/)
2. Install [ruby on rails 2.3](http://railsinstaller.org/en) (This step may not be required)
3. run cmd.exe as administrator
4. navigate to directory where arachni package was downloaded in my case I used command cd C:\Users*****\Desktop
5. run downloaded **arachni-1.4-0.5.10-windows-x86_64.exe** using command line.
6. step 5 will extract files to directory **C:\Users*****\Desktop\arachni-1.4-0.5.10-windows-x86_64**
7. navigate to **C:\Users*****\Desktop\arachni-1.4-0.5.10-windows-x86_64\bin** and run **arachni_web.bat** from the command line this should generate local web access point to arachni web interface **http://localhost:9292/** use this in your browser to access the interface.
8. web interface will ask you to login. Default login details are in the **C:\Users*****\Desktop\arachni-1.4-0.5.10-windows-x86_64\README.txt**

Default account details:

```
Administrator:
    E-mail address: admin@admin.admin
    Password:       administrator

User:
    E-mail address: user@user.user
    Password:       regular_user
```

Comment: You don't need steps 2 and 3, just double click on the exe, it'll extract everything automatically in the current working directory.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I didn't feel the need to document that past the obvious notice under the link itself:The executable will automatically extract Arachni in the current directory, please download using Save as… instead of running directly from the browser.